# 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

```
f = open("key.txt", 'rb')
k= f.read()
def bits(f):
    bytes = (ord(k) for k in f.read())
    for k in bytes:
        for i in xrange(8):
            yield (k >> i) & 1
for k in bits(open('key.txt', 'r')):
    print k

kt= [k[57],k[2],k[4],k[43]]

print kt
```

I am getting an error which says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "k.py", line 11, in <module>
    kt= [k[57],k[2],k[4],k[43]]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How do I rectify it ?

Comment: Some more details like ' what is the input file like' would be nice.

Comment: you already did `print k` - what does it show you?

Answer (score 0):

Since `bits()` will yield an integer which is assigned to `k` on line `for k in bits(open('key.txt', 'r')):` the index operator on line `kt= [k[57],k[2],k[4],k[43]]` naturally fails because `int` doesn't have `__getitem__` defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `bits(...)` a name:

```
x = list(bits(open('key.txt', 'r')))
for k in x:
    print k

kt = [x[57], x[2], x[4], x[43]]
```

Yours wasn't working because `k` is assigned to each item in `bits(...)`.  Once the `for` loop is finished, it will still equal the last item.  Instead, you need to give the whole thing a name.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning you are doing,

```
k = f.read()
```

And later when you are trying to do,

```
kt= [k[57],k[2],k[4],k[43]]
```

You are basically using the first `k`, because this is the only `k` visible from this scope. Hence, you are getting the error.

You might want to remove the loop and do something like this.

```
k = list(bits(open('file.txt', 'r')))    
kt = [k[57], k[2], k[4], k[43]]    
print kt
```